# Prove that matrix is Hermitian iff it's equal to its adjoint with general hermitian inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, self-adjoint-operators, hermitian-matrices

The Wikipedia article for Hermitian matrices gives an alternative characterization for Hermitian matrices [link](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hermitian_matrix#/Equality_with_the_adjoint). The statement I want to prove is:
$$ A^* = A \iff \langle w,Av \rangle_H = \langle Aw,v \rangle_H $$
This was proven for the standard inner product by a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3306900/prove-that-a-matrix-is-hermitian-iff-it-is-equal-to-its-adjoint).
I want to prove it for the general case with an arbitrary hermitian inner product on complex vector spaces.
I tried it using
$$ \langle w,Av \rangle_H = w^*HAv $$
with $H$ being a hermitian matrix and $ * $ marks the hermitian conjugate of a vector/matrix.
I don't really know how to show it without using that H and A commute.

I am thankful for any help!

Edit:

Note that I am using a positive definite hermitian form as the definition for the inner product. A hermitian form is defined as a sesquilinear form with $\langle w,v \rangle = \overline{\langle v,w \rangle}$.

Then there exists a hermitian matrix H being the transformation matrix of the hermitian form with
$$ \langle w,v \rangle_H = w^*Hv $$

Comment: Just to be clear: your definition of the inner product is $\langle x, y\rangle_H=x^* H y$?

Comment: @DavidRaveh yes exactly, I added it to the question.

Comment: Your definition of the inner product isn't valid, since it doesn't generally satisfy $\langle x,x \rangle_H\geq 0$

Comment: @DavidRaveh you're right. I clarified it a bit. please see the edit in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between this proof and the one you linked is mostly symbolic. We *define* the adjoint of $A$ denoted by $A^\dagger$ by $\langle A^\dagger i|j\rangle=\langle i|Aj\rangle$.

**For any inner product**, if $A=A^\dagger$
then $$A_{ij}=\langle i|Aj\rangle=\langle Ai|j\rangle=\langle j|Ai\rangle^*=A_{ji}^*$$
so $A$ is Hermitian. The converse follows by going in the opposite direction as well.

Comment: I think I don't quite get it then. Isn't $\langle Ax, y\rangle_H = (Ax)^*y$ (copied from the other question) Implying that $ H = I $ with $ I $ being the identity matrix. Or is it that the basis can be chosen to fulfil $ H=I $?

Comment: @exploitingDev I didn't realize that they didn't use general notation, so I edited to redo it. If you have any questions about how I defined the adjoint, we can go to a chatroom

Comment: Thanks for your help. It makes sense now.